# web scraping from the same level multiple nodes with the same names

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I would like to extract the following data from four nodes all at the same level and sharing the same code name.

```
# I was able to extract the first of the four nodes - Property Amenities, using google chrome selector gadget as to identify the nodes.  

library(rvest)
page0_url<-read_html ("https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g1063979-d1447619-Reviews- 
Solana_del_Ter-Ripoll_Province_of_Girona_Catalonia.html")
result_amenities <- html_text (html_node(page0_url,"._1nAmDotd") %>% html_nodes("div") )
```

However, I cannot figure out how to pass the code to extract the elements within the second object named "Room Features". This is at the same node level and has the same name code as the one above =.This is also the case for the two objects following to this last one and by the names of "Room types" and "Good to know".

Comment: Did neither of these answers below solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to query all of the nodes with same class using the `html_nodes()` function then parse each of those nodes individually.

For Example

```
library(rvest)

url<- "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g1063979-d1447619-Reviews-Solana_del_Ter-Ripoll_Province_of_Girona_Catalonia.html"

page0_url<-read_html(url)
result_amenities <- html_text(html_nodes(page0_url,"._1nAmDotd") %>% html_nodes("div") )

names <- html_nodes(page0_url,"div._1mJdgpMJ") %>% html_text()
groupNodes <- html_nodes(page0_url,"._1nAmDotd")
outputlist <-lapply(groupNodes, function(node){
   results <- node %>% html_nodes("div") %>% html_text()
})
```

On the reference page there is no corresponding "_1nAmDotd" node the "Good to Know" section thus leading to an unbalance in the results.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all desirable data (including everything you requested) is available via the page manifest, within a script tag, as that is where it is loaded from. You can regex out that enormous amount of data with regex. Then write user defined functions to extract desired info.

I initially parse the regex matched group into a json object `all_data`. I then look through that list of lists to find strings only associated with the data of interest. For example, `starRating` is associated with the location data you are interested in. `get_target_list` returns that list and then I extract from that what I want. You can see
that `location_info` holds the data related to hotel amenities (including room amentities), the star rating (hotel class) and languages spoken etc.

[image]

E.g. `location_info$hotelAmenities$languagesSpoken` or `location_info$hotelAmenities$highlightedAmenities$roomFeatures` ........

N.B. As currently written, it is intended that `search_string` is unique to the desired list, within the list of lists initially held in the json object. I wasn't sure if the names, of the named lists, would remain constant, so chose to dynamically retrieve the right list.

---

**R:**

```
library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)

is_target_list <- function(x, search_string) {
  return(str_detect(x %>% toString(), search_string))
}

get_target_list <- function(data_list, search_string) {
  mask <- lapply(data_list, is_target_list, search_string) %>% unlist()
  return(subset(data_list, mask))
}
    
r <- read_html("https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g1063979-d1447619-Reviews-Solana_del_Ter-Ripoll_Province_of_Girona_Catalonia.html") %>%
  toString()

all_data <- gsub("pageManifest:", '"pageManifest":', stringr::str_match(r, "(\\{pageManifest:.*);\\(")[, 2]) %>%
  jsonlite::parse_json()

data_list <- all_data$pageManifest$urqlCache
# target_info <- get_target_list(data_list, 'hotelAmenities')

location_info <- get_target_list(data_list, "starRating") %>%
  unname() %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  {
    .$data$locations[[1]]$detail
  }
```

---

**Regex:**

[image]